# How to apply radix sort (uses counting sort) with struct containing multiple strings

Tags: c, struct, radix-sort, counting-sort

I want to alphabetically sort the struct strings with radix sort, however I am struggling to apply radix sort to check each digit of the strings. I checked other posts but I couldn't find a structure similar to mine.
The problem is that my code checks for each ENTRY of the struct not EACH digit of the string in that entry. (By entry I mean; table[0], table[1] etc.) So basically it sorts the string in itself of each entry. I couldn't build the logic, can someone help me please?

EDIT: the length of the strings are not the same

Here is my code:

```
typedef struct FUNCTIONS_STRUCT
{
    char *fncName;
    void (*fnc)(char *);
    char *description;
} FUNCTIONS_STRUCT_t;

FUNCTIONS_STRUCT_t FUNC_TABLE[] =
{

        { "ABCD", ABCD, "" },
        { "abcD", abcD, "" },
        { "EaBB", EaBB ,""}
        //it goes on ..

};

// Function to find the Largest Number
int getMax(int array[], int n) {
  int max = array[0];
  int i;
  for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    if (array[i] > max)
      max = array[i];
  return max;
}
// Function for Count sort
void countSort(int array[], int n, int dig) {
  int output[n];
  int i, count[10] = {0};

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    count[(array[i] / dig) % 10]++;

  for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    count[i] += count[i - 1];

  for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    output[count[(array[i] / dig) % 10] - 1] = array[i];
    count[(array[i] / dig) % 10]--;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    array[i] = output[i];

}

void radixsort(int array[], int n) {
  //Get the largest number to know the maximum number of digits
  int m = getMax(array, n);
  int dig;

  //Counting sort is performed for every digit
  for (dig = 1; m / dig > 0; dig *= 10)
    countSort(array, n, dig);
}

int main()
{
    int functionTableUnitSize = sizeof(FUNC_TABLE) / sizeof(FUNC_TABLE[0]);
    radixsort(&FUNC_TABLE, functionTableUnitSize);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In this case, each "digit" is a character, so it should be a radix sort using base 256. If all of the names are 4 characters long, the counts which are converted into indexes could be kept in a [4][256] matrix.

Comment: Names of the form "*_t" are reserved for the implementation.  You are polluting the namespace.  Don't use `FUNCTIONS_STRUCT_t` for your own use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the function names in your question have a uniform length of 4 alphanumeric characters. In C, identifiers can use 63 different alphanumeric characters from these groups:

- lower case (abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)
- upper case letters (ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ)
- digits (0123456789)
- and the underscore (_)

Different encodings have a different order (e.g. EBCDIC lower case letters are sorted before upper case letters, while the reverse is true for ASCII). For a portable C programm we can therefore define our own lexical sorting order.

We can do this for example in a function called build_lexical_sorting_index.

**Details**

- I have minimally adjusted the naming from the code you provide in your question
- your functions must work with FUNCTION arrays and not with int arrays
- radix_sort first creates the lexical sorting index
- count_sort must then be called for each of the 4 alphanumeric characters of a function name
- words are usually sorted from the leftmost character, that's why we do it this way
- count_sort is then called for each of the 4 characters
- this determines the index from the lexical_sorting index of the corresponding character from the function name
- then the count sorting algorithm as shown in your question is applied
- at the end the result is printed

If one slightly modifies your code according to the above mentioned points, it looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define UNIFORM_FUNCNAME_LENGTH 4

typedef struct {
    char *fnc_name;
    void (*fnc)(char *);
    char *description;
} FUNCTION;


void ABCD(char *a) {};
void abcD(char *a) {};
void EaBB(char *a) {};
void A012(char *a) {};
void _ABC(char *a) {};

FUNCTION func_table[] = {
        {"ABCD", ABCD, ""},
        {"abcD", abcD, ""},
        {"EaBB", EaBB, ""},
        {"A012", A012, ""},
        {"_ABC", _ABC, ""}
        //it goes on ..
};
int lexical_sorting_index[256] = {0};

int lexical_index(int ch) {
    return lexical_sorting_index[ch];
}

void count_sort(FUNCTION *array, int n, int char_position) {
    FUNCTION output[n];
    int count[256] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int ch = array[i].fnc_name[char_position];
        int index = lexical_index(ch);
        count[index]++;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++)
        count[i] += count[i - 1];

    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int ch = array[i].fnc_name[char_position];
        int index = lexical_index(ch);
        output[count[index] - 1] = array[i];
        count[index]--;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        array[i] = output[i];
}

void build_lexical_sorting_index() {
    int nr = 0;
    for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)
        lexical_sorting_index[i] = nr++;
    for (int i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)
        lexical_sorting_index[i] = nr++;
    for (int i = '0'; i <= '9'; i++)
        lexical_sorting_index[i] = nr++;
    lexical_sorting_index['_'] = nr;
}

void radix_sort(FUNCTION *array, int n) {
    build_lexical_sorting_index();
    for(int char_position = UNIFORM_FUNCNAME_LENGTH - 1; char_position >= 0; char_position--)
        count_sort(array, n, char_position);
}

int main() {
    int table_size = sizeof(func_table) / sizeof(func_table[0]);
    radix_sort(func_table, table_size);

    for (int i = 0; i < table_size; i++)
        printf("%s ", func_table[i].fnc_name);
    return 0;
}
```

When the program is executed, the following is displayed in the debug console:

```
abcD ABCD A012 EaBB _ABC
```

Comment: thank you, but I should have clarified that the length of the strings are not the same

Comment: the code can be adjusted accordingly, similar to how you first determine the maximum number of digits in the code in your question, here you need to determine the maximum length of the string and adjust the sorting function accordingly